# The Z shell returns "number expected" when I try to remove a directory

Tags: zsh

Why can't I delete this directory in the Z shell? What number is expected?
I have tried googling "number expected" and z shell to no avail.

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 me  staff     96 Jan 31 09:49 PycharmProjects
drwxr-xr-x+   3 me  staff     96 Apr 21  2015 Sites
drwxr-xr-x@  13 me  staff    416 Jul  1  2019 iCloud Drive (Archive)
drwx---rwx@  39 me  staff   1248 Dec  5 12:28 iCloud Drive (Archive) 2

me@BigT ~ % rmdir -rf iCloud Drive (Archive)
**zsh: number expected**
```

Comment: Save yourself tons of typing with tab completion. Just write `rmdir -rf iC`<TAB> When you have multiple matches, you can hit Tab again to cycle. Not only will you avoid having to type the whole name, it'll be automatically quoted as well.

Comment: @Mthibode : Parenthesis have a special meaning in filename expansion, so if your filename contains such a special character (such as `*[]()?`), you have to put it inside quotes or escape it using `\\`.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but it may be only one part of the problem:

Comment: mthibode@BigT ~ % rm -rf "iCloud Drive (Archive)"
rm: iCloud Drive (Archive): Operation not permitted

Comment: You are supplying 4 separate arguments to `rmdir`: `-rf`, `iCloud`, `Drive`, and `(Archive)`, not a single argument `iCloud Drive (Archive)`. `(Archive)` is being interpreted as a series of glob qualifiers, with `c` being the qualifier expecting a numeric argument.

Comment: mthibode@BigT ~ % rm -rf 'iCloud Drive (Archive)'
rm: iCloud Drive (Archive): Operation not permitted

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the spaces and parenthesis are making ZSH try to expand / evaluate your expression, which is invalid. Try surrounding the name of the folder with quotes, like so:

```
rm -rf "iCloud Drive (Archive)"
```

Comment: mthibode@BigT ~ % rmdir -rf "iCloud Drive (Archive)"
rmdir: illegal option -- r
usage: rmdir [-p] directory ...
mthibode@BigT ~ % rmdir -rfp "iCloud Drive (Archive)"
rmdir: illegal option -- r

Comment: That's an entirely separate question, but `rmdir` doesn't *take*  those options. Keep using `rm`, as `rmdir` will *only* remove an empty directory. (`rmdir -p` will start at the then end of a path, removing the directory if empty, then recursively removing the parent if *it* is now empty, etc.)